# Nested "for" loop inside "if" condition in Liquid/Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm getting syntax error while trying to generate site. Do you have any ideas what can be wrong here?

Error:  Liquid syntax error: Unknown tag 'elsif'

```
{% if page.title == "Tags" %}
    {% for tag in site.tags %}
{% elsif page.title == "Categories" %}
    {% for tag in site.categories %}
{% endif %}
  <a href="#{{ tag[0] | slugify }}">{{ tag[0] }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't start a loop conditionally like that, control blocks must be properly nested. To accomplish what you're trying to do you could do:

```
{% if page.title == "Tags" %}
  {% assign data = site.tags %} 
{% elsif page.title == "Categories" %}
  {% assign data = site.categories %}
{% endif %}

{% for tag in data %}
  <a href="#{{ tag[0] | slugify }}">{{ tag[0] }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got it all wrong. The nested loops does not work this way.
It should start and end inside the same conditional.

```
if conditional
    for loop

    endfor
endif
```

something like this.

So, the correct way to do it should be this

```
{% if page.title == "Tags" %}
    {% for tag in site.tags %}
        <a href="#{{ tag[0] | slugify }}">{{ tag[0] }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% elsif page.title == "Categories" %}
    {% for tag in site.categories %}
        <a href="#{{ tag[0] | slugify }}">{{ tag[0] }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This code should do exactly what you want correctly but there is a better approach as answered by [JJJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/jjj)